# Was "potency set" used for power set?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, reference-request, set-theory

Cross posted at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/457909/37385)

For historical reasons, the English term "power set" in set theory is a translation of the German "Potenzmenge", which is still in use in German mathematical literature.

Did some English language mathematics use the term "potency set" for power set, and if so, what are good references.

Comment: Previously asked in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457909/potency-set-for-power-set ... there, the conclusion was that "potency set" was never used in English.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar It is indeed true that the question was asked there. But the participants here are different, and the fact that no-one there found a use does not show that the term was never used in English.

Comment: [Re](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/was-potency-set-used-for-power-set#comment37069_15911), I think that @GeraldEdgar did not mean to stymie discussion here, only to make participants here (not all, but not none, of whom are also participants at MO) aware of existing discussion.  It is generally appropriate to edit a link to a cross post into both questions; I have edited your MO question accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the clarification and the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper Rieger, L.
"On the consistency of the generalized continuum hypothesis."
*Rozprawy Mat.* 31 (1963) described in MR0146091, which can be downloaded from http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-5ca4b532-4aa3-4856-924f-8bbed25e3c33 (click on the "31. książka") uses the phrase "potency set axiom" on pp 15, 20, 38 (and maybe elsewhere).

When discussing the "potency set axiom" Rieger refers to axiom C3 in Gödel's 1940
*The Consistency of the Continuum Hypothesis*
(Annals of Mathematics Studies, Princeton), whose text is reproduced in vol II of the 1990 edition of Gödel's *Collected Works*. Towards the end of Chapter II (on p.32 of the *Collected Works*) is  a group of 4 axioms, labeled "Group C".  Gödel describes the third of them as providing for the existence of a "set including the set of all subsets" of a given set, but does not use any of the terms "Potenzmenge", "power set" or "potency set".

So I suppose  Rieger translated the usual term "Axiom der Potenzmenge" (used by Zermelo in his 1907 paper) into English, with the help of a dictionary, not knowing that  "power set" is idiomatic and that  "potency set" is never used. (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladislav_Rieger) for info about Rieger's life.)

Comment: Many thanks! Do you know the first name of L. Rieger?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Ladislav Svante Rieger.  According to Math Genealogy he had 73 descendants.  His degree was from Charles University and his first publications were in Czech journals, so I doubt English was his first language.

Comment: May you post your answer to https://mathoverflow.net/q/457909/37385 as well, please?

Comment: One might add that Reiger's paper was published in a Polish journal/bookborsu, where a mistranslation to English might not have been caught.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is difficult to overestimate the abilities of the Polish mathematical community, and the term is not a mistranslation. It has, on the other hand, relevance that Rieger grew up in a country where German was one of the official languages, so he may therefore have preferred the more literal translation.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal A more literal translation seems a mistranslation to me, since "power set" is jargon. Like translating "corps locaux" as "local bodies" instead of "local fields." And "power" is, according to my dictionary, is a more common translation of "Potenz." "Potency" is not a commonly used word in English, except in "drug potency," and much less common than power or potential.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know that mistranslations have clear individuation criteria. On this topic, confer the comments at https://mathoverflow.net/q/457909/37385.

Comment: MR0106832  (of  Wegel, Herbert
_Axiomatische Mengenlehre ohne Elemente von Mengen._,
Math. Ann. 131 (1956)) is by L. Rieger, who says near the end of  his review "the power of the potency-set", meaning I am sure "the cardinality of the power set".

Comment: Did Zermelo introduce the term “Potenzmenge” in 1907?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal  I assume so, but don't actually know.  Google Books shows that Z and Hessenberg in 1908 were early users.  I can't find the term in a quick skim of Cantor's collected works.

Comment: @kimchilover It seems to me that Zermelo's paper was from 1908 - https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fbf01449999. I will read it to check if Zermelo coined the term. It is interesting if Cantor did not come up with it.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal You are right, but I am right, too.  The article appeared in Band 65, Heft 1, dated 13 December 1907, as seen on https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0065?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B5%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.485%2C%22y%22%3A0.761%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A0.455%7D . If you skip to the end of the article, you see it was submitted on 30 July 1907, as shown on https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0065?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B291%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D . When the last Heft of volume 65 appeared it was 1908.